# Python - Where do I store data classes which are common across different files?

Tags: python-3.x, data-modeling

I'm working on a python wrapper for a REST API. I'm using python data classes to store the shape of the JSON response of each endpoint so developers have features like autocomplete and objects they can use from the response.

In 99% of the cases, I can maintain a separate python file for each end point.
So for `/cars` endpoint, I have a file called `cars.py` and for `/bikes`, `bikes.py`. Each python file has a self contained `@dataclass` representing the JSON returned by functions within the endpoint.

Following this practice, there's endpoint like `/maintainence/` and an associated `maintainance.py`. This endpoint can return a car or bike object plus some extra info.

What's the recommended good practice to import the data model from `bike.py` or `car.py` into `maintainence.py`?
Do I create a separate python files just for the modules?
Is it okay to import the data class from adjacent python files?

Comment: Sure, it's okay to import data classes from another file, even a very small file. What other sensible alternative is there even?

Comment: thanks @KilianFoth. I was overthinking this and needed a 2nd opinion to stop spending too much time on minor things